# Jsoup long parse() execution

Tags: java, android, json, parsing, jsoup

I using [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) to send `POST` request. Then I need to parse this data as text in `JSON` form.

Also I wrote some code to check execution time becouse it takes much more time then I want.

```
Connection connection = Jsoup.connect("http://api.3botinka.com/api/synchronize")
                    .method(Connection.Method.POST)
                    .cookies(cookies)
                    .timeout(30000)
                    .ignoreContentType(true);
            if (data != null) {
                connection.data(data);
            }

            res = connection.execute();

            Logger.d(System.currentTimeMillis() - t2 + " = connection.execute");

            long t6 = System.currentTimeMillis();
            String tmp = res.parse().outerHtml();
            Logger.d(System.currentTimeMillis() - t6 + " = res.parse().outerHtml()");

            long t4 = System.currentTimeMillis();
            rezult = Jsoup.parse(tmp, "UTF-8").text();
            Logger.d(System.currentTimeMillis() - t4 + " = Jsoup.parse");
```

And what I got in Logcat:

```
1588 = connection.execute
16150 = res.parse().outerHtml()
1466 = Jsoup.parse
```

`parse()` method have extra long execution time and I don't know how to solve this problem. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution of this problem.

There is other method in `Jsoup` lib to get content of page without parsing.

The solution is change this line:

```
String tmp = res.parse().outerHtml();
```

on this line:

```
String tmp = res.body();
```

It is realy faster in 20 times. May be they do different work, but in my needs it's the same.